# Governance Registry REST API Adding states

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

How to get the governance registry lifecycles using this api https://localhost:9443//governance/restservices in payload of json.I am getting all the field but i am not getting lifecycle value in that api.Can anyone suggest how to get that.I also see this api to get lifecycle state GET https://localhost:9443/ /governance/restservices/44dadw4/states but I dont want to use this api because I have to call for each time this api to get its lifecycle state.I want to use this api https://localhost:9443//governance/restservices and get the rest service lifecycle value in json payload.

Please help i am searching in web for this approach but not getting enough result.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way getting LC details from `https://localhost:9443//governance/restservices` using vanilla WSO2 G-Reg. This endpoint is used to retrieve rest service artifact metadata.

I don't understand your point, why you can't use `https://localhost:9443/ /governance/restservices/44dadw4/states` endpoint for this. [Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Governance+REST+API#GovernanceRESTAPI-Getlifecyclestateofanasset).

However, You can achieve this using a custom deployment. If you want to get LC details from this endpoint you have to update the existing API code. Basically you need to update [Asset.java](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-governance/blob/master/components/governance/org.wso2.carbon.governance.rest.api/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/governance/rest/api/Asset.java#L134) and deploy the new governance.war file.

Comment: i have grid where i need to show the data of the above api governance/restservices.for eg suppose now i have 50 records i have to hit 50 times this api governance/restservices/44dadw4/states to get the state and bind again to data which i got from prev api not good so way

Comment: Well as I mentioned in my above answer you should create a new governance API(governance.war), I have pointed the starting point above(Asset.java).